# How to use csv variables when filling repeated web pages

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I'm trying to automate the filling out of a repeated web page using csv data in selenium. These posts, [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050075/filling-out-web-form-data-using-built-in-python-modules) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668340/how-can-i-get-this-simple-python-login-program-to-loop) have been very helpful.

Specifically, I want to enter data into a .csv file (product sku and description), use that data to fill out a web form (it registers the product), submit the form, and finally repeat the process for as many product skus in the .csv file. I understand the XPATH and selenium selectors but cannot figure out how to properly loop the csv data in order to register only one product per loop.

Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
class FormPage(object):
    def fill_form(self, data):
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "item_#isbn"]').send_keys(form_data['collection_isbn'])
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "title_#title"]').send_keys(form_data['collection_description'])
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "contrib_#0#0#name_sort"]').send_keys(form_data['company'])
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "market_#0#pub_date"]').send_keys(form_data['pub_date'])
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "price_#0#0#1#price"]').send_keys(form_data['price'])

        find_by_xpath('//td/select/option[@value = "348"]').click()  # binding
        find_by_xpath('//td/select/option[@value = "47617"]').click()  # subject
        find_by_xpath('//td/select/option[@value = "14"]').click()  # contributor
        find_by_xpath('//td/input[@name = "chkbox_contrib_#0#0#corporate_ind"]').click()  # company check
        find_by_xpath('//td/select[@name = "price_#0#0#1#rc_price_type_uid"]/option[@value = "12"]').click()  # price type
        find_by_xpath('//td/select/option[@value = "902"]').click()  # currency
        find_by_xpath('//td/select/option[@value = "805"]').click()  # target market

        return self

form_data = {
    'collection_isbn': '978',
    'collection_description': 'desc',
    'company': 'company',
    'pub_date': '2019',
    'price': '10000'

file = open('C:/Users/Desktop/isbn_data.csv')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)

row_count = sum(1 for row in file)
print(row_count)
file.seek(0)

login_success = False
while login_success == False:
    LoginPage().input_login(login_cred)
    LoginPage().login_click()
    if driver.current_url == "https://www.bowkerlink.com/corrections/common/home.asp":
        login_success = True
        print("Login Success")
        break
    else:
        print("Login Failed")

find_by_xpath('//a[@href = "/corrections/bip/bl_ItemEdit.asp"]').click()
FormPage().fill_form(form_data)
```

Comment: unrelated, but use a context manager for the file opening.  Then within that context manager, do a for loop over the file.

Comment: use `for`-loop to read row from file and to run function which will use this row with form - `for row in file: function_fillig_form(row)`. OR read all rows to list in memory and then use `for`-loop to get row from list and to run function. `for row in list: function_fillig_form(row)`

Comment: I’m glad to see other people mention context managers. You should not compare booleans using `==`. `login_success == False` —> `login_success is False` —> `not login_success`. You’re probably even better off just using a `while True` and breaking. Hilariously enough, you are actually breaking out of the loop, which means `login_success` is completely useless. Anyway, you haven’t really mentioned what the problem is. What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Selenium, but there is probably a better of way checking whether the login was successful, no?